# Wrong behave of a regex

Tags: regex

```
/^(x+)+(x+) % \1 = \2$/.test("xxxx % xx = x")
```

Return `true`, which should be `false`

```
/^(x+)+(x+) % \1 = \2$/
```

Return `["xxxx % xx = x", "xx", "x"]`

In this case `xxxx` = n*`xx` + `x`, that's impossible.

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and Safari with JavaScript.

Also in Python.

Comment: You have to escape `+`, like this: `\+`.

Comment: Can you give a better explanation or more examples so we can see how a valid string should look like? Currently I have no Idea what you wanted to achieve with the `+` between the two capturing groups.

Comment: try http://www.regexpal.com for instant test for regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is your assumption that Group 1 is the start of the string is wrong.

Have a look at the group break up here (taken from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rN0eB3/1)):

[image]

You can see the Group 1 actually includes the `x`s starting from the 2nd position in the string, and Group 2 is actually the last `x` from the 1st word.

Why does it happen? Because a regex engine tries to match a string with the given pattern by all means. Here, `(x+)+` tries to match as many `x`s as possible and store them in a capturing group buffer. However, backtracking is working here intensively to accommodate for the next `(x+)` before the space, and make sure the captured group texts are valid for back-references.

So, the engine is checking all `xxxx` from Position 1, cannot accommodate for the last `(x+)` (as there must be at least 1 `x`), backtracks, finds `xxx` and also sees that it can accommodate the `(x+)`, but the back-reference requirement later (\2) is not satisfied. Thus, the engine fails, and goes on to check the string at the next position (#2). It performs all the steps, and finally matches the whole string, as the back-reference condition is satisfied.

**UPDATE**

As per discussion below, you seem to need a regex that only accepts a string with odd number of `x` in the first word. @swenzel's suggestion is correct then:

```
^(x+)\1*(x+) % \1 = \2$
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rN0eB3/2)

Comment: That is the first group, just not the one matched, as it is repeated and only the last match is what appears. Perhaps the assumption that `(x+)+` will match multiple groups of same elements is wrong. As you said, it tries to do what it can to match string, and first `x` and then `xx` is fine.

Comment: The important information is shown on the right (also regex101): *Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.* The problem therefore is the `+` between the capturing groups.

Comment: @swenzel So the first group catches "x" and then "xx", and the 2nd group catches the last "x"?  That would make sense then.  (x+)+ does not mean "match group in the same way one or more times".

Comment: This unfortunately also means it isn't possible using regex (at least in javascript).

Comment: @Neil depends on what OP wants to do... from what I see removing the `+` would be sufficient. But that is guessing. Without any further examples I have no Idea what is considered to be valid and what is not.

Comment: @swenzel I think he wants to also match say `xxxxx % xx = x`, which means it can't be done.

Comment: @Neil `/^(x+)\1*(x+) % \1 = \2$/` ;)

Comment: @swenzel Very nice.  :)

Comment: @swenzel My mistake is that I think the `(x+)+` will do a group catch multipul times with the **same** content.In fact the engine just do `x+` multiple times.So the group 1 is actrually `["x", "xx"]` in the two time loop.Thank u!

Comment: @amow: Do you mean you want to only allow odd number of `x` in the first word? I added swenzel's suggestion to the question body. Shall I explain how it works?

Comment: @amow if you really want to do a modulo like thing then also my expression above won't work, see for example "xxx % x = xx" which will match. You need to make sure that \2 does not start with \1, you can do that with a negative lookahead like this: `/^(x+)\1*(?!\1)(x+) % \1 = \2$/`

Comment: Ah and by the way @stribizhev it does not necessarily contain an odd amount of characters. `xxxxxx % xxxx = xx` matches as well ;)

Comment: @swenzel: Surely, when you also modify the second part.